# Trading Log Program using Java Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I am coding a stock trade log program & since the logic to be achieved is complex (for me atleast), posting here to seek guidance from the experts. I am not seeking the complete code or something but just on how to structure the Java Stream to achieve this if its possible. My search in this forum & google on this did not yield much, apologies if its wrong to post this here.

**Description**

3 trades (Buy - Sell or Sell - Buy is 1 trade) are executed as per details below. I need to add the quantity & average the price per trade-leg individually i.e. buy & sell separately per trade. The time stamp should be the earliest when the trade is opened (buy or sell) & the latest when that trade is closed (sell or buy). Also need to replace the Order No. column with the Tag column which shows the Trade numbers

**Data from Excel**

- Trade Date | Trade Time | Description | Buy/Sell | Qty | Rate | OrderNo.
- 18-1-2017 | 09:30:45 | CompanyCar | B | 1000 | 450.25 | 10101011
- 18-1-2017 | 09:30:45 | CompanyCar | B | 1000 | 450.30 | 10101011
- 18-1-2017 | 10:07:45 | CompanyCar | S | 1000 | 453.50 | 10101345
- 18-1-2017 | 10:08:00 | CompanyCar | S | 1000 | 453.50 | 10101345
- 18-1-2017 | 11:30:15 | CompanyBike | S | 2000 | 80.25 | 10104343
- 18-1-2017 | 11:40:45 | CompanyBike | S | 2000 | 81.35 | 10104765
- 18-1-2017 | 12:20:55 | CompanyBike | B | 4000 | 82.10 | 10105789
- 18-1-2017 | 13:40:25 | CompanyBike | S | 4000 | 84.35 | 10108790
- 18-1-2017 | 14:30:15 | CompanyBike | B | 2000 | 82.80 | 10108844
- 18-1-2017 | 15:10:45 | CompanyBike | B | 2000 | 80.50 | 10114567

**Expected output after processing with Java Streams**:

- Trade Date | Trade Time | Description | Buy/Sell | Qty | Rate | Tag
- 18-1-2017 | 09:30:45 | CompanyCar | B | 2000 | 450.28 | Trade1
- 18-1-2017 | 10:08:00 | CompanyCar | S | 2000 | 453.50 | Trade1
- 18-1-2017 | 11:30:15 | CompanyBike | S | 4000 | 80.80 | Trade2
- 18-1-2017 | 12:20:55 | CompanyBike | B | 4000 | 82.10 | Trade2
- 18-1-2017 | 13:40:25 | CompanyBike | S | 4000 | 84.35 | Trade3
- 18-1-2017 | 15:10:45 | CompanyBike | B | 4000 | 81.65 | Trade3

The data is provided in an excel file & the code I have so far is as below. I am stuck after data extraction from excel

**Code**

```
public class TempTradeLog {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Read data from excel file (using Apache POI to read XLSX file)
    iFaceXLSX iFaceXLSX = new excelXLSX();
    File fileTradeLog = new File("E:\\TradeLog_2017.XLSX");
    List<List<XSSFCell>> dataTradeLog = iFaceXLSX.readData(fileTradeLog);

// Skip first 4 lines as it is not relevant       
dataTradeLog = dataTradeLog.stream().skip(4).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
}
```

**Note** to read excel data I referred to [Link](http://www.java67.com/2014/09/how-to-read-write-xlsx-file-in-java-apache-poi-example.html)

Comment: What is the criterion precsely for rows being added? In your input, CompanyBike is sold three times, the two of them are added, the third is not, why? Are the tags just consecutive Trade1, Trade2, … Trade9, Trade10, …?

Comment: @OleV.V. Sorry for that error, have updated my query now. Hope it is clear. Yes the trade numbers are running numbers as you mention

Comment: Sorry about being unclear. CompanyBike is sold in amounts of 2000, 2000 and 4000. From your description I would expect all three sales to be added, yielding 8000. Why is that not so?

Comment: @OleV.V. In the CompanyBike example I first sell 2000, then instead of closing that with a buy I additionally sell 2000, so now the total sell is 4000. I close this with a buy of 4000. So this constitutes as 1 trade. The next buy or sell of CompanyBike will be treated as the next trade. Hope now the example makes it clear.

Comment: So I seem to understand that only rows that come right after each other should be added? If so, streams may not be the best for the job (obviously they can be used if you insist).

Comment: @OleV.V. I am not really sure if Streams is the right way but if such a thing is possible would be neat is what I feel, want to avoid the for loop as much as possible. Since the data will be sorted by the Description followed by Date & Time we can go in sequential manner netting the buy's & sell's. If this can be done via Streams any pointers on how I should go about.

Comment: Frankly, avoid streams for what you are trying to do. Streams are great for processing each element of a list, and for grouping element by some criterion, but not if the criterion includes they come right after each other. You would need to have the stream remember the last item, which goes against the idea of a stream and would require a hack. I could do it, but it’s too cumbersome, I don’t want to invest the time and effort.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thank you for your time & inputs. For now will get this working using the good old FOR loop, but will try to see if I can get this working with Streams, if nothing atleast it will help me learn Streams better